# Representation a matrix as a colored square shape

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, matrix

I am sure that I have accidentaly seen before a way to construct a square shape corresponding to a matrix. For example if we have a `5*5` matrix:

```
matrix = {
  {1,-1,1,1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,1,1}, {1,1,1,-1,1}, {-1,1,-1,1,-1}, {1,1,1,-1,-1}};
```

display as a square representation:

[image: colored squares]

But I cannot remember where I have seen this issue.

Comment: Use `MatrixPlot`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update 2020-01-07

At this point there is a Wolfram Function Repository (WFR) [`RandomScribble`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomScribble).

Here is matrix representation with "midriff" random scribbles based WFR's `RandomScribble`:

```
matrix = 
   {{1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1}, 
    {1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, 
    {-1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, 
    {1, 1, 1, -1, -1}};

SeedRandom[23];
Magnify[Grid[
  matrix /. {-1 :> OrangeScribble[], 1 :> DarkGreenScribble[]}, 
  Dividers -> All], 0.4]
```

[image]

(Note that
[this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/234987/34008)
by @kglr has a different approach to making "midriff" scribbles. )

#### Definitions

```
Clear[OrangeScribble];
OrangeScribble[opts___] := 
  ResourceFunction["RandomScribble"][opts, 
   "EnvelopeFunctions" -> Automatic, "NumberOfStrokes" -> 200, 
   "RotationAngle" -> Pi/4, ColorFunction -> "SiennaTones", 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, AbsoluteThickness[3]}];

Clear[DarkGreenScribble];
DarkGreenScribble[opts___] := 
  ResourceFunction["RandomScribble"][opts, 
   "EnvelopeFunctions" -> Automatic, "NumberOfStrokes" -> 200, 
   "RotationAngle" -> Pi/4, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, AbsoluteThickness[3]}];
```

---

### Original answer

```
matrix = 
{{1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, 
{-1, -1, -1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, 
{-1, 1, -1, 1, -1}, 
{1, 1, 1, -1, -1}};

SeedRandom[23];
Grid[matrix /. {-1 :> OrangeScribble[], 1 :> DarkGreenScribble[]}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

#### Update

> A problem: If I change the number of raws and columns, then the size of the shape goes very big. I wish to change my matrix to for example :10*10.

```
matrix2 = ArrayFlatten[Table[matrix, 2, 2]];

Magnify[Grid[
  matrix2 /. {-1 :> OrangeScribble[], 1 :> DarkGreenScribble[]}, 
  Dividers -> All], 0.4]
```

[image]

#### Definitions

```
Clear[RandomScribble];
Options[RandomScribble] = 
  Join[{AbsoluteThickness -> 2, ColorFunction -> ColorData[87]}, Options[Graphics]];
RandomScribble[nPoints_Integer, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := RandomScribble[nPoints, \[Pi]/4, opts];
RandomScribble[nPoints_Integer, dir_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{r, absTh, colorFunc},
   
   absTh = OptionValue[RandomScribble, AbsoluteThickness];
   colorFunc = OptionValue[RandomScribble, ColorFunction];
   
   If[! (NumericQ[absTh] && absTh > 0), Return[$Failed]];
   
   r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nPoints, 2}];
   
   Graphics[{
     AbsoluteThickness[absTh], colorFunc[0], 
     BezierCurve[Sort[r].RotationMatrix[dir]]
     },
    FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]
   ];
```

```
OrangeScribble[] := RandomScribble[RandomInteger[{160, 190}], \[Pi]/4, ColorFunction -> (Orange &), ImageSize -> Tiny];
DarkGreenScribble[] := RandomScribble[RandomInteger[{120, 180}], \[Pi]/4, ColorFunction -> (Darker[Green] &), ImageSize -> Tiny];
```

Comment: You are unbelievably intelligent. However I draw my picture just in paint, you redraw the exact shape

Comment: A problem:  If I change the number of raws and columns, then the size of the shape goes very big. I wish to change my matrix to for example :`10*10`. The desire case is the same size. Where do I must change to have the same size for the shape?

Comment: @InzoBabaria Thanks! As for plotting the 10x10 matrix: you can use `Magnify` or change the values given to `ImageSize`. (See my update.)

Comment: More a moment, I panicked that they added `OrangeScribble` and `DarkGreenScribble` to Mathematica.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yeah, WL obviously has to have those functions! I made a resource function submission [`RandomScribble`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/antononcube/DeployedResources/Function/RandomScribble) that should fill that gap.

Comment: @QuantumDot There is a resource function [`RandomScribble`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomScribble) now.

Answer (score 6):

As @AntonAntonov says, use [`MatrixPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html):

```
matrix = {{ 1, -1,  1,  1, -1},
          {-1, -1, -1,  1,  1},
          { 1,  1,  1, -1,  1},
          {-1,  1, -1,  1, -1},
          { 1,  1,  1, -1, -1}};

MatrixPlot[matrix, 
           ColorRules -> {-1 -> Orange, 1 -> Darker@Green},
           Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I misunderstood the meaning of square color before, here is my new answer:

```
matrix = Array[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] &, {10, 10}];
positionA = Position[matrix, 1];
positionB = Position[matrix, -1];
Grid[matrix, Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {None, None, 
   Join[Rule[#, Green] & /@ positionA, 
    Rule[#, Orange] & /@ positionB]}, 
 ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Join[Rule[#, White] & /@ positionA, 
    Rule[#, Black] & /@ positionB]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A variation on Anton's cool idea:

```
ClearAll[bsf, scribleShading]

bsf[n_: 200][t_] := BSplineFunction[Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[
    Table[{x, RandomReal[{-.2, .2}] + (Pi - Abs[x - Pi]) RandomReal[{.75, 1}] Sin[30 x]},
       {x, Sort@RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]}]. RotationMatrix[
          RandomReal[Pi/4 + {-Pi/32, Pi/32}]]]], SplineDegree -> 7][t];

scribleShading[n_: 200][color_: Red, absolutethickness_: 3] := 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate @ bsf[n][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[color, AbsoluteThickness[absolutethickness]],
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
   ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]
```

***Examples:***

```
Grid[Table[Show[scribleShading[][RandomColor[]], ImageSize -> 100], 3, 5], 
    Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

To get a graphics object:

```
Graphics[Translate[Scale[scribleShading[][RandomColor[]][[1]], .9], #] & /@ 
  Tuples[{Range @ 5, Range @ 3}], 
 ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False,
 GridLines -> Range /@ {5, 3}, PlotRange -> Thread[{1, 1 + {5, 3}}]]
```

[image]

Using OP's `matrix`:

```
Grid[matrix /. {-1 :> Show[scribleShading[][Orange], ImageSize -> 90],
     1 :> Show[scribleShading[][Darker@Green], ImageSize -> 90]}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
pos = Association[# -> Position[Reverse /@ Transpose[matrix], #] & /@ {1, -1}];

Graphics[MapThread[Module[{col = #2, val = #}, 
     Map[{Translate[Scale[scribleShading[][col][[1]], .9], #], 
         Text[Style[val, 40, FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"], .5 + #]} &][pos@val]] &] @ 
  {{-1, 1}, {Orange, Darker @ Green}}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False,
 GridLines -> Range /@ Dimensions[matrix], 
 PlotRange -> Thread[{1, 1 + Dimensions[matrix]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your intelligence and skills are indescribable!!!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
Graphics[{
  Raster[Reverse@matrix, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Orange, Darker@Green}, #] &)]
  },
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`ArrayMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayMesh.html):

```
ArrayMesh[matrix, MeshCellStyle -> 
  {{2, All} -> Darker@Green, {2, PositionIndex[Flatten @ matrix] @-1} -> Orange}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayMesh[matrix, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} ->  Darker @ Green,
      {2, PositionIndex[Flatten@matrix]@-1} -> Orange}, 
 MeshCellLabel -> MapIndexed[{2, #2[[1]]} -> Style[#, 20] &, Flatten[matrix]]]
```

[image]