# Drawing a RegionPlot from a Table of Values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions, discrete

[image]I have a 2-D table with numbers 1,2,3,4 and 5 populated in it in a continuous form.
From it, I like to create a region plot with five regions separated in this space. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

```
matrix = {{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,5,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,5,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{5,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}
```

Comment: does this give something close to what you have in mind : `ListDensityPlot[Reverse@matrix, InterpolationOrder -> 0]`?

Comment: I cannot use color. I need to achieve this goal without using colors, but only boundary to separate the regions.

Comment: or  `ListContourPlot[Reverse@matrix, Contours -> (Union[Flatten@matrix] - 1/2), ContourShading -> None]`?

Comment: This is much closer to what I want. Can we remove the colors and make it transparent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListContourPlot[matrix, Contours -> (Union[Flatten@matrix] - 1/2), 
 ContourShading -> None, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

**Update:** *" a way to make the lines on the contour plot show the step shape as in the real table"*:

```
contours = ComponentMeasurements[matrix, "Contours"];

Graphics[Values @ contours]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[matrix, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Values @ ComponentMeasurements[matrix, "Contours"]}, 
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the lines on the contour plot show the step shape as in the real table? @kglr

Comment: @Monire, please see the update.

Comment: @MonireJalili Maybe this variant is helpful: `HighlightImage[Colorize[matrix, ImageSize -> Medium], {Black,  Values@ComponentMeasurements[matrix, "Contours"]}]`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

```
matrix = Array[RandomChoice[Range[5]] &, {10, 10}]; Table[
 RegionPlot[RegionUnion[Rectangle /@ Position[matrix, i]], 
  PlotPoints -> 180, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]], {i, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Or

```
matrix = Array[RandomChoice[Range[5]] &, {10, 10}];
Table[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[RandomColor[]], 
   Rectangle /@ Position[matrix, i]}], {i, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

**Original**

[Representation a matrix as a colored square shape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234838/representation-a-matrix-as-a-colored-square-shape/234839#234839)

Maybe like this.

```
matrix = Array[RandomChoice[Range[5]] &, {10, 10}];
position1 = Position[matrix, 1];
position2 = Position[matrix, 2];
position3 = Position[matrix, 3];
position4 = Position[matrix, 4];
position5 = Position[matrix, 5];
background = {None, None, 
   Join[Rule[#, Green] & /@ position1, Rule[#, Orange] & /@ position2,
     Rule[#, Cyan] & /@ position3, Rule[#, Yellow] & /@ position4, 
    Rule[#, White] & /@ position5]};
itemstyle = {Automatic, Automatic};
Grid[matrix, Frame -> All, Background -> background, 
 ItemStyle -> itemstyle]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is a very cool solution. However, I am reserving the color to show a third dimension in my data. So I cannot use color. I need to simply use boundaries and borders to separate the regions from each other.

Comment: @MonireJalili My updated can solve your problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem. I added an image in my original post to make my question a bit more clear.

Comment: @MonireJalili Please post your matrix instead of picture.

Comment: Sure, I just did it. Does it work this way?

Answer (score 1):

"ListInterpolation" and "Reverse" commands can be used to obtain smooth curves. Note that while defining "func" below, {1, 10} and {20, 30} represent the minimum and maximum value of the x - and y-axis, respectively. Also, a smoother plot can be obtained with more data points.

```
func = ListInterpolation[Reverse[matrix, {2}], {{1, 10}, {20, 30}}]; 
Show[
 RegionPlot[{func[x, y] >= 0, func[x, y] < 1.2, 
   2.4 < func[x, y] < 3.4, func[x, y] > 4.7}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 20, 30},
   BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x-coordinate", 14, Black, Bold], 
    Style["y-coordinate", 14, Black, Bold]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Comments to another previous answer mention that the asker WANTS "the lines on the contour plot [to] show the step shape as in the real table". Your proposed solution seems to precisely eliminate that feature.